# How to get the employee_id for this select: SELECT MIN(hire_date) FROM employees;

Tags: sql

How to get the **employee_id** for this select:

```
SELECT MIN(hire_date) FROM employees;
```

I think this is the solution but it is not work:

```
SELECT MIN(hire_date), employee_id
FROM employees
GROUP BY employee_id
HAVING MIN(hire_date);
```

Comment: What's the expected result if there are two persons with the same min hire_date?

Comment: Tag the question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Core ANSI SQL answer, if your dbms doesn't support `FETCH FIRST`:

```
select *
from employees
where hire_date = (select min(hire_date) from employees)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `order by` and a limit of some sort.  The ANSI standard method is:

```
select e.*
from employees e
order by hire_date asc
fetch first 1 row only;
```

Databases have other methods for limiting the output to one row, including `rownum = 1`, `top`, and `limit`.

Comment: Thank you, but i am studing and i don´t know yet the rownum, top and limit method´s.